# How to use an angular module in a non-standalone component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the MatExpansionModule so I can use  so i have import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion'; in this page. And i import this page in app.module.ts but i get this error imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone.

Comment: You should only import `MatExpansionModule` in your module's imports array. Are you also trying to import it in the component you want to use it? It is not clear what you mean when you say "page" - do you mean component? Can you provide a small snippet of your module and component?